# Calculate percentages for variables within a certain time frame

Tags: r

I am trying to get frequency of the colors by month. Eventually I want to make a line graph with a line for each color, showing what percentage of all colors it was for each month. My data looks like this:

```
ID color   color2  color3  date
55 red     blue     NA     2020-03-15
67 yellow  NA       NA     2020-05-02
83 blue    yellow   NA     2020-05-17
78 red     yellow   blue   2020-12-15  
43 green   NA       NA     2021-01-27
29 yellow  green    NA     2021-01-03
```

I need something like this so I can make the graph:

```
Month      freq_blue freq_red  freq_yellow  freq_green %_blue %_red %_yellow %_green
03-2020       1        1          0           0            50    50     0       0
04-2020       0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
05-2020       1        0          2           0            33.3  0      66.7    0
06-2020       0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
07-2020       0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
08-2020       0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
09-2020       0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
10-2020       0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
11-2020       0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
12-2020       1        1          1           0            33.3  33.3  33.3     0
01-2021       0        0          1           2            0     0     33.3    66.7
```

I'm trying to group by month and then calculate the frequencies but I'm having some trouble because there are multiple `color` columns.

Comment: It might be easier if you use dput() for your example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tidyverse` (and `lubridate`).

First, you can put your colors into long format with `pivot_longer`. You can remove rows that have missing colors/values.

Then you can calculate frequencies with `count` after grouping by the month, year, and color (value). By grouping by month and year, you can calculate proportion (percentage).

Finally, you can put your data into wide form if desired with `pivot_wider`. The function `complete` is also used to fill in missing months and colors.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

df %>%
  mutate(month = month(date), year = year(date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("color")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(month, year, value) %>%
  count() %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(year, month = 1:12, value = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green"), fill = list(n = 0, percent = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(month, year), names_from = value, values_from = c(n, percent))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 24 × 10
   month  year n_blue n_green n_red n_yellow percent_blue percent_green percent_red percent_yellow
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
 2     2  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
 3     3  2020      1       0     1        0        0.5               0         0.5          0    
 4     4  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
 5     5  2020      1       0     0        2        0.333             0         0            0.667
 6     6  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
 7     7  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
 8     8  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
 9     9  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
10    10  2020      0       0     0        0        0                 0         0            0    
# … with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- tibble(ID = c(55,67,83,78,43,29),
             color = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "yellow"),
             color2 = c("red", NA, "yellow", "yellow", NA, "green"),
             color3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "blue", NA, NA),
             date = c("2020-03-15", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-17", "2020-12-15","2021-01-27", "2021-01-03"))



dat <- df %>% mutate(month = as.yearmon(date)) %>% group_by(month)%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(color, color2, color3)) %>% mutate(val = 1) %>% drop_na() %>%
  select(month, value, val) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols= month, names_from=value, names_prefix = "freq_",values_from = val, values_fn = sum) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(freq_red, freq_blue, freq_yellow, freq_green)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(freq_red =0, freq_blue = 0, freq_yellow = 0, freq_green = 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, as.double) %>%mutate(`red_%` = round(freq_red/rowSums(.[2:5])*100,2),
                                                           `yellow_%` = round(freq_yellow/rowSums(.[2:5])*100,2),
                                                           `blue_%` = round(freq_blue/rowSums(.[2:5])*100,2),
                                                           `green_%` = round(freq_green/rowSums(.[2:5])*100,2))
```